# Conversion of 2d coordinates to 3d coordinates

Tags: three.js, raytracing

In my project previously i used 2d Map. as per costumer requirement they want 3d map. But 3rd party provide only X and Y. In that project some Objects are static so I placed manually. But some Objects are dynamically changed the position. That object need X , Y , Z How to internally convert X Y to X Y Z

**Some Static Objects Coordinates : in 2D X: 865 Y: 950
In 3d X:-54.2,Y:11**.6,Z:17.5

**in 2D X: 813 Y: 945
In 3d X:-54.4,Y:12.4,Z:24.1
2D Map**

Comment: It's not very clear, what your problem is. If you're asking for an idea, then this is not that type of question on SO.

Comment: Why would you need a z coordinate?   If you 2d plane with the map on it is at z:0, then wouldn't you just place your object at z:0 so it is on the map? Seems to me you are over thinking things.

Comment: @2pha , 2d to 3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the relation between xy coordinates in 2D and xz coordinates in 3D. When you get it, you’ll solve a half of the question.
Next, to find y in 3D. I would use **THREE.Raycaster()** with THREE.Vector(0, -1 ,0) direction and its origin is higher than the highest point on the 3D map.